Dimension of ( generic or special ) fiber of base change morphism
Let $f:X\to Y$, $ g: T \to Y$ be morphisms of schemes with fiber product
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X \times_Y T @> \pi_1>> X\\
@V \overline{f}:=\pi_2 V V @VV f V\\
T @>>g> Y  \tag{1}
\end{CD}
Then for $ t\in T $ with $y:= g(t) \in Y$, $ \dim \pi_2^{-1}(t) = \dim f^{-1}(y) $ ? If it is not true in general, when will it be possible?
EDIT : I think that it may be true if $f$ is (locally) of finite type. Note that
$$ \pi_2^{-1}(t)=(X \times_Y T) \times_T \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t) \cong X \times_Y \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t) \cong (X \times_Y \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y))\times_{\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y)}\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t) = f^{-1}(y) \times_{\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y)} \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t). $$. And note next Proposition :

Proposition 5.37 ( Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, p.134 ). Let $X$, $Y$ be non-empty $k$-schemes locally of finite type. Then $$ \dim X\times_k Y = \dim X + \dim Y.$$

Also, note that $f^{-1}(y)$, $\mathrm{Spec}\kappa(t)$ are locally finite type over $\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y)$ since $f$ is locally of finite type and 'locally of finite type' is stable under base change. So by the Proposition 5.37, $ \dim \pi_2^{-1}(t) = \dim f^{-1}(y) + \dim \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t) = \dim f^{-1}(y).$  Correct? Is the 'locally of finite type-ness of $f$' alone really enough to prove our question?
______________________________________________________________
$\divideontimes$ ( Can be skipped ) Let's consider next some special case :
Let  $f: X\to Y$ be a surjective proper flat morphism of finite presentation. The $Y$ can be affine scheme. Let $T = \mathrm{Spec}A$ is the specturm of discrete valuation ring, and $\eta \in T$ is the generic point, and $s\in T$ is the closed point. Let $y:=g(\eta)$ and $y':=g(s)$. Now let's again consider the fiber product $(1)$ above. By the stability under base change, $\pi_2$ is also surjective proper flat morphism of finite presentation (?). Then in this case, $\dim \pi_2^{-1}(\eta) = \dim f^{-1}(y)$ and $\dim \pi_2^{-1}(s)=\dim f^{-1}(y')$?
$\divideontimes$ In fact, I want to understand next statement ( Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Vol.1.,
Proof of Proposition 14. 123 )

(2) Let $f: X\to Y$ be a surjective proper flat morphism of finite presentation between noetherian schemes with $Y$ is affine and set $V:= \{ y\in Y : \dim f^{-1}(y)=0 \}$. ( We can prove that $V$ is open ( omitted ) ). Then $V$ is closed under specialization.

Note next Proposition ( Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Vol.1., Proposition 15.7 )

Proposition 15.7. Let $Y$ be a scheme, and let $y\neq y'$ be two points such that $y'$ is a  specialization of $y$. Let $\iota : \kappa(y) \to K$ be a field extension. Then there exists a valuation ring $A$ with $\mathrm{Frac}A =K$ and a morphism $g: \mathrm{Spec} A \to Y$ with $g(s)=y'$ and $g(\eta) =y$ such that the induced morphism $\kappa(y) \to \kappa(\eta)=\mathrm{Frac}A$ is given by $\iota$. Here $s \in \mathrm{Spec}A$ is the closed point and $\eta \in  \mathrm{Spec} A$ is the generic point. Moreover, if $Y$ is locally noetherian and $K$ is a finitely generated extension of $\kappa(y)$, we may in addition assume that $A$ is a discrete valuation ring.

Then Gortz states that " By Proposition 15.7 above, to show the $(2)$ above, it is enough to show the following statement" :

(3) Let $T$ be the spectruem of discrete valuation ring, $\eta \in T$ the generic point, $s\in T$ the closed point, and $f: Z \to T$ a proper flat morphism such that $\dim f^{-1}(\eta) =0$. Then $\dim f^{-1}(s)=0$ also.

Why the statement $(3)$ is enough to show the $(2)$? My first attempt is as follows : Let $y'$ be a specialization of $y\in V \subseteq Y$. We need to show $y' \in V$ also ; i.e., $\dim f^{-1}(y') =0$. By the proposition 15.7 , for some suitable finitely generated field extension $\iota : \kappa(y) \to K$, there exists a discrete valuation ring $A$ with $\mathrm{Frac} A =K$ and a morphism $g: T:=\mathrm{Spec} A \to Y$ with $g(s)=y'$ and $g(\eta)=y$ such that the induced morphism $\kappa(y) \to \kappa(\eta) = \mathrm{Frac} A$ is given by $\iota$. Here $s\in T$ is the closed point and $\eta \in T$ is the generic point. Again consider fiber product ( letting $Z:= X \times_Y T $ ):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Z:=X \times_Y \mathrm{Spec} A @> \pi_1>> X\\
@V \overline{f}:=\pi_2 V V @VV f V\\
T:=\mathrm{Spec} A @>>g> Y  \tag{4}
\end{CD}
If our original question is true, then $\dim \pi_2^{-1}(\eta) = \dim f^{-1}(y)$ and $\dim \pi_2^{-1}(s)=\dim f^{-1}(y')$. Since $y\in V$, $\dim f^{-1}(y)=0$. So $\dim \pi_2^{-1}(\eta) =0$. Now apply the statement $(3)$ ( substitute $\pi_2$ to $f$ in $(3)$ ). Then $ 0 = \dim \pi_2^{-1}(s)=\dim f^{-1}(y')$. So $y' \in V$, which is desired. But our original question is true? Can anyone help?

In fact, $$\pi_2^{-1}(t) \cong f^{-1}(g(t))$$ by the basic properties of Cartesian squares; in particular, their dimensions are the same.

Oh, really? Perhaps can you explain the isomorphism-how to use the basic properites of Cartesian squares- more friendly? Any hint? A part that makes me a little bit puzzled is,  if the above isomorphism is true, then by combining with the calculation in the EDIT ( in my question ),  $f^{-1}(y) \times_{\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y)} \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t) \cong f^{-1}(y)$. But it seems that this isomorphism does not holds in general unless the induced ring homomorphism $\kappa(y) \to \kappa(t)$ induced from the $g : T \to Y$ is isomorphism. How do you think about this point out?

A fiber is the fiber product with a point. So, $\pi_2^{-1}(t)$ fits into a Cartesian square with $\pi_2$, and since the union of two Cartesian squares is Cartesian, it is also the fiber of $f$.

What two Cartesian can we think of? Can you present them more explicitly? I tried to two case of two union of Cartesian squares but it only yelds that $\pi_2^{-1}(t)  \cong f^{-1}(y) \times_{\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y)} \mathrm{Spec} \kappa(t)$, not $\pi_2^{-1}(t) \cong f^{-1}(y)$. Perhaps, have you ever tried your proposal?
